# Is this a safe way to work with a .p12 certificate?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

In my Rails app, I am using a 3rd-party service that gave me a .p12 certificate and a password. I use this certificate to sign, make soap requests, among others.

I don't want to upload the .p12 file to the GitHub repository, so the solution I can think of is to hardcode the certificate's path in the controller:

```rb
class MyController < ApplicationController
   def create
      response = ExternalService.call(
        certificate_path: "#{Rails.root}/config/certificates/{Rails.env}.p12"
        certificate_pass: Rails.credentials.service[:pass]
      )
   end
end
```

And then provide the .p12 files individually.

I would like to know if this is too complicated?

**Extra info:**

This is how the service's `.call` method reads the certificate:

```rb
file = File.read(certificate_path)
OpenSSL::PKCS12::new(file, certificate_pass)

# Should this be done differently?
```

Comment: You haven't mentioned what version of Rails you're using, but assuming Rails 5+, you may want to consider using credentials to store the content of the p12 file in a key. This solves the issue of needing to read the file on each `.call` and deployment. https://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/security.html#environmental-security

Comment: @JohannsGregorian Hey Johanns, Rails is 6.0.3.1. The content of my certificate is a lot of different characters (I guess because it is a .p12). Maybe I should generate a different representation of the certificate? You are completely right regarding reading the file on each call, I am going to improve that.

Comment: To clarify, is the ``ExternalService`` service object something you've written or from a gem provided by the 3rd party service?

Comment: @rmlockerd It is a gem I made myself